# Какой тип счетчика выбрать?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет!!!
Скажите, пожалуйста, какой тип данных лучше выбрать для поля счетчика?
Я читал книги, и там как-то невнятно обясняется целый тип...
Какой диапазон чисел целочиселных типов?
Помогите, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1):

Выбирать стоит положительный целочисленный тип, который минимально покроет необходимое количество записей. Чем больше тип вы берете, тем больше перерасход памяти будет. По крайней мере его всегда можно будет изменить в большую сторону.

По диапазонам и подобным вопросам стоит в первую очередь обращаться к официальной документации.

[11.2.1 Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)